# How are xsd schema ref and type attribute values' namespaces aliased/bound?

Tags: xml, firefox, xsd, namespaces

Given a couple of example XSD definitions:

http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd

https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

Both XSD documents define elements, attributes, attributeGroups and/or types that self-reference other definitions within the same document. In the case of the first, these types seem to be namespaced using the `saml` namespace alias/binding. Example:

```
<attributeGroup ref="saml:IDNameQualifiers"/>
```

and in the case of the second, they are namespaced using the `ds` namespace alias/binding. Example:

```
<element ref="ds:SignedInfo"/>
```

However, viewing either document in Firefox, I cannot see in either document where these namespace aliases or bindings are defined.

The first document's root element gives a `targetNamespace` attribute:

```
targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
```

as does the second:

```
targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
```

but is it just convention that aliases the first to `saml` and the second to `ds`? If so, where could one look to find these conventions? If not, what is going on to resolve these namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace bindings are defined (as is best practice) in the root element of the schema with `xmlns:` attributes:

saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd

```
<schema
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
  [...]
  targetNamespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
  [...]>
```

xmldsig-core-schema.xsd

```
<schema
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  [...]>
```

These bindings do not only apply to element and attribute names (in a schema, which is also an XML document, they are mostly in the XML Schema namespace or in no namespace), but also to **attribute values that are declared as QNames** in the associated schema (in this case, [the XML Schema Schema](https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd)).

This is the case of the `ref` and `type` attributes (quoting from the above linked schema schema):

```
<xs:attribute name="ref" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:QName"/>
<!-- observe how the declaration for the type attribute uses itself! -->
```

This is the reason why, in any schema that references its own element/attribute/type declarations and that has a target namespace, this target namespace needs to be bound to a prefix (or made default) for use in the `ref` and `type` attribute values.

In a nutshell, the key idea to understanding the machinery involved here is to forget, for a moment, that the two *.xsd* documents are schemas, and to see them instead as any other XML documents that are valid against the XML Schema Schema. And more: the XML Schema Schema is an XML document as well, which is valid against... itself. This is how XML Schema bootstraps itself.

Comment: I thought that would be the case, but I couldn't see any `xmlns` attributes when I was examining the schemas. It turns out that Firefox doesn't show these in it's default XML viewer, but they were there all along. *facepalm*

Comment: Apparently this is a [long standing problem](https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/604358-why-do-xml-schema-attributes-disappear#post_message_2380915)